# How to remove overlapping strokes in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, stroke

I want to remove black line between the larger and the smaller rectangle.

[image]

Using *Path → Exclusion* resulted in this ugly two smaller lines.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Got it fixed by making the each stroke, filled, and literary overlapping each others. My previous attemp has two strokes that just "touching" to each others.

[image]

Then using *Path* -> *Union*.

[image]